# Instabot python plugin not working on cloud services

Tags: python, instagram, instagram-api

I'm currently up at 5:30 trying to figure out how to host my Instagram bot it works fine on my pc but every time I try and use cloud services It displays a 429 error and waits for 5 minutes then 10 then 15. I own an Ubuntu server I pay for on vultr and it doesn't work there. I tried pythonanywhere, I tried repl.it . But it comes up with the same error. How do I resolve this?